# length limitation for string type in ORC and parquet

Tags: cloud, data-warehouse, parquet, orc

I wonder what is the appropriate data type for storing long text using ORC and Parquet format. Does any of these two format has length/size limitation for its default string type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The default string type `UTF8` in Apache Parquet has not length limitation, you can save an arbitrary length string in it. This is a variable length type, i.e. only the length of the string stored is used in the resulting file.